# TextField and Select doesn't change- React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I'm new in full stack developing and I'm trying to code something to understand better frontend with React JS. I've been using also redux but never had an error. I've been trying to write a list of field, from a firebase document, that I can modify from the known data and send back to server. But each TextField and Select does not change their values:

```
class PostDialog extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    oldPath: '',
    newPath: '',
    Code:"",
    barrCode:"",
    color:"",
    size:"",
    qnt:"",
    brand:"",
    cat:"",
    price:"",
    createdAt:"",
    descr:"",
    errors:{}
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.openDialog) {
      this.handleOpen();
    }
  }
  handleOpen = () => {
    let oldPath = window.location.pathname;

    const { userHandle, postId } = this.props;
    const newPath = `/inv/${postId}`;

    if (oldPath === newPath) oldPath = `/inv`;

    window.history.pushState(null, null, newPath);

    
    this.props.getPost(this.props.postId);
    this.setState({ open: true, oldPath, newPath, size: this.props.size });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, this.state.oldPath);
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.clearErrors();
  };

  handleChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
  };
  onTodoChange(value){
    this.setState({
      barrCode: value
    });
}
  render() {
    const {errors} = this.state;
    const {
      classes,
      post: {
        postId,
        Code, barrCode, color,size,qnt,brand,cat,price,createdAt,descr,available
      },
      UI: { loading }
    } = this.props;


    const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
        const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
        const MenuProps = {
            PaperProps: {
              style: {
                maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
                width: 250,
              },
            },
        };

    const dialogMarkup = loading ? (
      <div className={classes.spinnerDiv}>
        <CircularProgress size={200} thickness={2} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <Grid container spacing={16}>
        <Grid item sm={7}>
          <hr className={classes.invisibleSeparator} />
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            {dayjs(createdAt).format('h:mm a, MMMM DD YYYY')}
          </Typography>
          <hr className={classes.invisibleSeparator} />
          <TextField
                                name="barrCode"
                                type="text"
                                label="Codice a Barre"
                                placeholder="111111111"
                                rows="1"
                                error={errors.barrCode ? true : false}
                                helperText={errors.barrCode}
                                className={classes.TextField}
                                value={barrCode}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            <TextField
                                name="price"
                                type="text"
                                label="Prezzo"
                                placeholder="111111111"
                                rows="1"
                                error={errors.price ? true : false}
                                helperText={errors.price}
                                className={classes.TextField}
                                value={price}
                                onChange={this.handleChangePrice}
                                fullWidth
                            />
                            <Box display="flex" flexDirection="row">
                              <Box>
                              <InputLabel id="brand">Marca</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="Marca"
                                            id="brand"
                                            value={brand}
                                            onChange={this.brandChange}
                                            input={<Input />}
                                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                                        >
                                        {brands.map((brand) => (
                                            <MenuItem value={brand}>
                                            {brand}
                                            </MenuItem>
                                        ))}
                                        </Select>
                              </Box>
                              <Box>
                              <InputLabel id="cat">Categoria</InputLabel>
                                        <Select
                                            labelId="Marca"
                                            id="cat"
                                            value={cat}
                                            onChange={this.catChange}
                                            input={<Input />}
                                            MenuProps={MenuProps}
                                        >
                                        {cats.map((cat) => (
                                            <MenuItem value={cat}>
                                            {cat}
                                            </MenuItem>
                                        ))}
                                        </Select>
                              </Box>
                              
                            </Box>
                            
                             
        </Grid>
        <hr className={classes.visibleSeparator} />
        <DeletePost postId={postId} />
          {/* <CommentForm postId={postId} /> */}
          {/* <Comments comments={comments} />  */}
      </Grid>
    );
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MyButton
          onClick={this.handleOpen}
          tip="Modifica"
          tipClassName={classes.expandButton}
        >
          <UnfoldMore color="primary" />
        </MyButton>
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm"
        >
          <MyButton
            tip="Close"
            onClick={this.handleClose}
            tipClassName={classes.closeButton}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </MyButton>
          <DialogContent className={classes.dialogContent}>
            {dialogMarkup}
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

PostDialog.propTypes = {
  clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  postId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  post: state.data.post,
  UI: state.UI
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
  getPost,
  clearErrors
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapActionsToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(PostDialog));
```

I've no idea about how resolve this, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
handleChange=(event)=>{
    this.setState({ ...this.state, event.target.name: event.target.value });
  };
```

Edit
Also change the values in html inputs to be like `value={this.state.[somevalue]}`

```html
<TextField
    name="barrCode"
    type="text"
    label="Codice a Barre"
    placeholder="111111111"
    rows="1"
    error={errors.barrCode ? true : false}
    helperText={errors.barrCode}
    className={classes.TextField}
    value={this.state.barrCode}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    fullWidth
/>
```

Comment: i think i missed a `;` at the end of that line

Comment: You missed the brackets around the variable property name, it should be `{ ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }`